# VueJS - 'undefined' when using the store to update the state

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have a form in VueJS where you can enter the customer information. Once the data has been inputted and you click 'Submit' then what it does is the following:

1. Calls an action which stores the customers details into the database using `axios`
2. Commits the result to a mutation which updates the object
3. A watcher watches for the change in the data and then updates the object within the main vue.

The code I have written is:

> Action

```
addCustomer: function (context, payload) {
   axios.post(`/customers`, {
     customer_name: payload.customer_name,
   }).then(function(message) {
      context.commit("FETCHCUSTOMER", {
        model: message.data.model
   });
});
}
```

> Mutation

```
FETCHCUSTOMER: function (state, payload) {
   state.customers.single = payload.model;
},
```

> Computed & watcher

```
customer_created() {
  return this.$store.state.customers.single;
}
// watcher 
customer_created() {
   console.log("Getting here - 1");
   var vm = this;
   vm.customer = this.$store.state.customers.single;
},
```

This is then called using a method `submit` which has the following:

```
this.$store.dispatch('addCustomer', vm.customer); 
console.log(vm.customer); // LOG 2
```

The issue is that `undefined` which relates to `LOG 2` is getting called before `Getting here - 1` log output is called meaning that when a user clicks submit, the customer is being created but I need to return the ID of that customer so I can progress in the system. This currently shows as `undefined` however, clicking on the button again shows the correct id..

Is there a way that I can do the following so that the state is updated without the need of clicking the submit button twice?

EDIT:

I have the following `computed`

```
customer_created() {
  return this.$store.getters.customers.single;
},
```

I have the following `watcher`

```
customer_created: {
   handler: function(val, oldVal) {
       console.log(val);
   },
   deep: true
}
```

This is only outputting `undefined` when I reload the page, but when clicking on the submit button which calls `this.$store.dispatch('addCustomer', vm.customer);` nothing is displaying?

Comment: Was the `undefined` issue fixed?

Comment: @KiraSan yes this is fixed thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Great, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Vuex `getters`.

In your store object, define it:

```
getters: {
  customers(state) {
    return state.customers
  }
}
```

Make sure your store `state` contains `customers`:

```
state: {
  customers: {
    single: null,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Then in your component `computed`:

```
customer_created() {
  return this.$store.getters.customers.single
},

customers() {
  return this.$store.getters.customers
}
```

You can watch it like this:

```
watch: {
  customers: {
    handler(newCustomers) {
      console.log('Customers changed')
      console.log(newCustomers.single)
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Or simply like this if you don't want to watch the customers object deeply.

```
watch: {
  customers(newCustomers) {
    console.log('Customers changed')
    console.log(newCustomers.single)
  }
}
```

**Vuex getters:** https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The one thing I'm confused about is the `watch` where does the `handler` come from? You have `newCustomers` here but I have no idea to where it comes from

Comment: When you watch an object deeply, you will need to add the deep flag to your watcher, so instead of defining the watcher as a function, we should instead define it as an object that has a handler function. I think it's not really needed in your case, you could just do it the simpler way as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have updated my question, please can you have a look? Everything is working apartment from the `watcher` and I can't figure out why

Comment: Sorry, the `submit` is being called before the `watcher` now.. If I output ``{{customer_created}}` inside the view then it's fine. Also, I'm passing the data of `customer_created` to ajax and it's showing as an empty object